# VueJS goBack from Dynamic Route

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have `/` and `/items/:name`

I go `/` then `/items/iphone5` then `/items/phone6`

Then call **$router.go(-1)** and that direct me to `/` instead of `/items/iphone5`

What's wrong?

---

**Update:**

`beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    this.toggleSideBar()
    next()
  }`

this code works, but dunno why not adding history,

then I create a promise to solve

`beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    this.toggleSideBar().then(() => next())
  }`

Comment: Can you give a minimal demo?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you uses **replace** option on your anchor.

please check out your  tag has this property

```
<router-link :to="..." **replace**>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Then call $router.go(-1) and that direct me to / instead of /items/iphone5

go method is based on [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

go(-1) returns to previous entry stored in the current history entry

> I go / then /items/iphone5 then /items/phone6

You have to inspect whether the history entry counts for your route or try using history mode

vue router default mode is hash.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})
```

Read [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html) for more info [Read caveats in the last and Server Side Rendering in first place if you have some time]